# error: typedef redefinition with different types

Tags: c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I try compile c++ lib in Android Studio with NDK and get some errors:

```
C:\AndroidSDK\ndk-bundle\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\..\lib64\clang\3.8.275480\include\stddef.h:62:23: error: typedef redefinition with different types ('unsigned long' vs 'unsigned int') typedef __SIZE_TYPE__ size_t; ^../../../../src/main/cpp/include\Crypto/Core/Types.h:20:22: note: previous definition is here typedef unsigned int size_t;
```

When I define

```
typedef unsigned long size_t;
```

I get:

```
C:\AndroidSDK\ndk-bundle\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\..\lib64\clang\3.8.275480\include\stddef.h:62:23: error: typedef redefinition with different types ('unsigned int' vs 'unsigned long') typedef __SIZE_TYPE__ size_t;^  ../../../../src/main/cpp/include\Crypto/Core/Types.h:20:23: note: previous definition is here typedef unsigned long size_t;
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: By *not* trying to redefine a standard type?

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel : [`size_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t).

Comment: https://www.viva64.com/en/k/0021/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`size_t` is already a data type defined by several C/C++ standards.
Try to typedef something else that is not already defined in language.

Example:-

`typedef unsigned long my_size_t;`

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `typedef` to redefine `size_t`. If you want to have a 32-bit unsigned integer, you can write:

```
typedef unsigned long u32t
```